# Google Charts Axis Pattern/Format Adding Comma Instead Of Decimal

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization, linechart

No matter what I try, my gridline labels on both vertical and horizontal axes are showing a comma for a decimal.

For example, my column values are 1.1 to 6.8 and the gridline labels show something similar to 5,28, 5,52, etc.

I've tried setting both Axis.format = '#,###.##' and data.cols[0].pattern = '#,###.##'. Neither work. Is the pattern wrong?

BTW, I'm using [angular-google-chart](http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/#/fat) and I double checked that the options are getting passed to the google api correctly, and they are.

I saw some people talking about formatters but I find it hard to believe that the default for Google charts is to add a comma.

Also, I read the linechart and axis documentation on Google thoroghly.

Please help!

Comment: Hi. If you're using the settings that were in sample.js in the project repository, they had french localization set. Try removing the language key from the config value or setting it to English.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for the help! Just getting used to google charts and angular-google-chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format-pattern doesn't define which characters will be used as decimalSymbol and groupingSymbol. The formatted value will depend on the language-settings of the browser(Accept-Language)

To force a specific format you must load the API in a language which uses the desired format(e.g. 'en')

---

### Some examples:

> german

(decimalSymbol: comma , groupingSymbol: dot)

```js
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['corechart'],language:'de'});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Y');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Z');
      

      data.addRows([
        [4000.1,  1001.11, 1002.12],
        [4000.2,  1001.51, 1002.82],
        [4000.3,  1001.31, 1001.12]
      ]);

      var options = {
         vAxis: {
          format: '#,###.##'
        }, 
         hAxis: {
          format: '#,###.##'
        }
             
      };
      
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
<div id="linechart"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

---

> french

(decimalSymbol: comma , groupingSymbol: space)

```js
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['corechart'],language:'fr'});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Y');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Z');
      

      data.addRows([
        [4000.1,  1001.11, 1002.12],
        [4000.2,  1001.51, 1002.82],
        [4000.3,  1001.31, 1001.12]
      ]);

      var options = {
         vAxis: {
          format: '#,###.##'
        }, 
         hAxis: {
          format: '#,###.##'
        }
             
      };
      
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
<div id="linechart"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

---

> english

(decimalSymbol: dot , groupingSymbol: comma)

```js
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['corechart'],language:'en'});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Y');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Z');
      

      data.addRows([
        [4000.1,  1001.11, 1002.12],
        [4000.2,  1001.51, 1002.82],
        [4000.3,  1001.31, 1001.12]
      ]);

      var options = {
         vAxis: {
          format: '#,###.##'
        }, 
         hAxis: {
          format: '#,###.##'
        }
             
      };
      
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
<div id="linechart"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

---